# Use of cognos viewer vs cognos query studio and report studio

Tags: cognos

In cognos, we design a model using framework manager and then we can use the model to build reports in Query Studio/Report Studio. However, there is another report viewing utility called cognos viewer. Why we need cognos viewer when everything can be done in query studio or report studio? Is it because cognos sdk uses cognos viewer to render the reports or any other reason for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Cognos viewer is simply the page which is shown when you're viewing report output.  For example :

- click on a report in Cognos Connection, it runs (you see the hourglass), then when its finished, you see the output in the Cognos  viewer
- run the report from Report Studio,  it runs (hourglass shown), then when its finished, you see hte output in the Cognos viewer